How to mirror node colors in Sankey visualization
I'm building a Sankey in a Microstrategy dossier that has the same set of six categories on both of two levels. Ideally I want each category to have the same color on both levels. However, all the options I'm finding relating to customized palettes and formatting don't seem to make it possible for the same color to be repeated across multiple nodes, especially in a way that's tied to the text value associated with the node. Is it possible to do this?
